# Movement from DataDog to Dynatrace

Tags: datadog, dynatrace

management.statsd.metrics.export.flavor=datadog

I was using datadog and now we are moving monitoring to Dynatrace, what will be the value of this property for Dynatrace.

management.statsd.metrics.export.flavor